# Setting Repeating Fields from a Workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow, designer-workflow

Is it possible to set the value of a multi-select box from a workflow?  I am working with a workflow that copies the data from a submitted form to several other forms, and there is a multi-select box that should be the same in each of them.  Is there a way to copy that data over?  If so, what format do I need to use?

**EDIT 1:**  I may have been unclear about this- I do not need to set the available options of the multi-selection box (they are already the same, as they are based on a list elsewhere in the site).  Rather, I need to set which items have been selected.

**EDIT 2:**  I just realized I was thinking of the wrong form- I actually need to set a repeating field, not a multi-selection (I realize they are almost the same, but I don't know if I could translate advice about one to advice about the other).

Answer (score 0):

Workflows are not meant to interact with UX as they should be used as means to automate processes. Rather consider setting field values through the workflow (in your case it might be using a multi-choice field) which should translate visually into your desired visual.

Comment: This is what I meant- I guess I phrased it wrong.  I want to set the field values of a form (I am creating the form with the workflow).  Two of the fields are multi-choice fields, but I'm not sure how to copy that information over.

Comment: but your form is actually backed-up by a list/library, right? so basically you should update the underlying list/library fields, which should be reflected in the form

Comment: Yes, but my question is how do I do that?

Comment: From within the workflow use any of the List item activities, either via "Copy List Item", or more particularly - "Set Field in Current Item" or "Update List Item" (http://generation12.wordpress.com/2008/12/16/update-list-item-or-set-field-in-current-item/)

Comment: I don't think you understand- I mean what sort of format do I have to use to set the field.  Can I enter a comma-separated list, or space separated, or what?

Comment: I think I see the disconnect here- see my edit above.